# Primefaces datatable do not show right columns after toggle action

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

i have primefaces datatable component with [Paginator](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/paginator.xhtml) and [ColumnToggler](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnToggler.xhtml).
Everything works fine until  toggle-off some columns and change page. Then columns which should be hidden are not mentioned in datatable header (this is ok), but data are still here. So datatable header is shorter than rest of datatable and columns do not shown under their headers. Primefaces version is 5.2.

Did someone face the same problem? What do you recommend to try/check?

Example:

Let's say that we i have table with 5 columns.

1. Id
2. Color
3. Name
4. Type
5. Price

In this table is about 100 records. One page shows 10 records so we have 10 pages. When we use ColumnToggler and 'toggle-off' price and type column. This will cause that these two columns will disappear. Problem occures if we choose different page via Paginator or just try change number of records showed on one page. After these operation i will get 'broken' table. Header of table will contains only first 3 columns (Id,Color,Name). This is ok, because last two columns should be hidden. So table header is filtered well. Problem is that table body contains all columns so also columns for Type and Price.

Unfortunatelly i can not provide screenshots because of character of data.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example and if you can reproduce the bug, please file a primefaces issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces

Comment: And try the latest PF code (build from source if needed)